# upload file to the Windows azure media services without using the local file path

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I'm trying to make an app wich will upload videofiles to the cloud. I found some examples that explain how to upload file to cloud from the local computer with using the file path. 
But i can't find how can i make an interactive app in which user can download video from web page.
Have anyone seeing something similar?

Comment: So are you looking to create a web page where users can add videos to the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look into http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/solutions/media/ . It describe main scenarios and capabilities of Microsoft Azure Media Services.

Developer portal for Azure Media Services located at
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/media-services/. It has getting starting articles covering following scenarios:

- Upload
- Encode
- Deliver
- Consume